# Couldn't load plugin 'processing' Ubuntu 14.04.5 Import Error

Tags: qgis, gdal, qgis-plugins, ubuntu, qgis-processing

I've upgraded QGIS to 2.18 in our Ubuntu 14.05.5 recently, in the process we have some dependency problems with PostGIS but solved updating sources repositories (using http://qgis.org/ubuntugis & http://qgis.org/ubuntugis-nightly-release trusty).
But we still have a problem loading 'processing' plugin in QGIS 2.18.0 start up, getting the following error message box, because undefined symbol:

```
GDALTranslateOptionsFree causes an Import Error:
Couldn't load plugin 'processing' 

ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/GDAL-2.1.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/osgeo/_gdal.so: undefined symbol: GDALTranslateOptionsFree 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 308, in loadPlugin
    __import__(packageName)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/__init__.py", line 28, in 
    from processing.tools.dataobjects import *          # NOQA
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/tools/dataobjects.py", line 37, in 
    from processing.algs.gdal.GdalUtils import GdalUtils
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/algs/gdal/GdalUtils.py", line 32, in 
    from osgeo import gdal
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/GDAL-2.1.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/osgeo/__init__.py", line 21, in 
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/GDAL-2.1.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/osgeo/__init__.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/GDAL-2.1.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/osgeo/_gdal.so: undefined symbol: GDALTranslateOptionsFree


Python version: 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:33:43) [GCC 4.8.4] 
QGIS version: 2.18.0 Las Palmas, d8f9d2e 

Python Path:
/usr/share/qgis/python
/home/tximikel/.qgis2/python
/home/tximikel/.qgis2/python/plugins
/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/GDAL-2.1.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode
/home/tximikel/.qgis2//python
```

Comment: Any issue of the sort I had (on manjaro) was linked to incompatible versions of sip, python and pyqt. Maybe try downgrading sip and pyqt and try again. Start by downgrading what was updated recently.

Comment: On my running installation, there is no `GDAL-2.1.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg`, so I guess it causes the problem. Try to install QGIS 2.14.8 from Ubuntugis without any files from qgis.org/ubuntugis repo.

Comment: I've solved the problem :) i've installed gdal v2.1 installed in my system, but PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH incorrecltly configured!

Answer (score 3):

I've solved the problem :) i already has installed gdal v2.1 in my system, but LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable incorrecltly configured! following i'll show more details to help solving similar issues:

- When i run $gdalinfo --version , and i get GDAL 2.0.0, released 2015/06/14, incorrect version
- Then i locate it with $which gdalinfo , and i get /usr/local/bin/gdalinfo
- Then i search whereis located my gdalinfo 2.1 version, $whereis gdalinfo , and i can see gdalinfo: /usr/bin/gdalinfo /usr/bin/X11/gdalinfo /usr/local/bin/gdalinfo /usr/share/man/man1/gdalinfo.1.gz
- So i test if /usr/bin/gdalinfo is 2.1 version? $/usr/bin/gdalinfo --version , as result i get an error: /usr/bin/gdalinfo: symbol lookup error: /usr/bin/gdalinfo: undefined symbol: EarlySetConfigOptions
- I check que problem is LD_LIBRARY_PATH, then i run $LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib:$LD_LIBRARY /usr/bin/gdalinfo --version , getting correct result: GDAL 2.1.0, released 2016/04/25
- To solve the problem i add this env variable to my $HOME/.bashrc adding the line: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
- Now the system get the correct GDAL v2.1 and start QGis with no problems loading processing plugin fine :)

Thanks & hugs great community ;) go on!

Comment: I forgot to mention that previosly i've installed GDAL 2.1 from sources, as suggested in: https://rdfactoryblog.wordpress.com/2016/09/03/qgis-2-16-on-ubuntu-studio-16-04/